Past or present perfect? in a doctor-patient dialogue
I have a question about the past and the present perfect tense in this dialogue.
Doctor: In which ear was the discharge worse? / has the discharge been worse?
Patient: It was worse in the left ear. / has been worse in the left ear.
I think that the hurt is continuing until now, so the present perfect will be right.
I want some advice. Thank you.

Either might be right. I would use "has been" if the discharge recurred or was still a problem. I would use "was" if it occurred once. I still might need to see the doctor about it is I still had a related problem (for example hearing loss).

@Peter - I would make this an answer. Both are correct but with different meanings, as you explain.

Either conversation could be right, but they mean slightly different things.
If the discharge had been recurring, or if the discharge was still a problem, the doctor would probably ask "In which ear has the discharge been worse", to which I would reply "It has been worse in the left ear."
On the other hand, the discharge may have only occurred once, or it may already have stopped. I may still need to see the doctor, either because I am worried about the discharge, or because it may be related to another problem I have. In this case the doctor would most likely ask "In which ear was the discharge worse", and I would reply "It was worse in the left ear."
